# Nil optional does not crash in Release

Tags: swift, crash, release

I have the following simple code in NSAppDelegate

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
  var opt:Int?
  NSLog("\(opt)")
  NSLog("\(opt!)")
  NSLog("done")
}
```

Now when I run that in debug mode it tells me what we all know about unwrapping nil optional. **But** when I run that for release it silently exits the app with no message at all. No console log. No dump. Nothing!

What's going on here?

Comment: doesn't release mode just turn off all runtime checks? (I simply suspect a null pointer dereference in the background, but try inspecting your code in the debugger.)

Comment: Yes, but then I expect a crash log at least! I mean how would you find out something in production here?

Comment: Aren't log outputs disabled in release? That would mean that the code is never executed...

Comment: @zisoft Well, imagine you have an app out there and it will not issue a crash log in that case. How are you supposed to find out the cause without a crash log??

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant (I forgot to address you above)

Comment: You got me wrong. I mean that `NSLog()` simply does nothing in release mode so your optional variable will not be unwrapped because it is inside the `NSLog()` call

Comment: @zisoft You got me wrong ;-) The first `NSLog`  prints "nil" and the 2nd will do the same as `exit(0)`. I definitely expect it to crash the app.

Comment: What version of Swift?

Comment: @GoZoner Swift version 1.1 (swift-600.0.57.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has asked me to check if the bug has been fixed with Xcode 6.3 beta 3 with Swift 1.2 (Build: 6D543q). Not sure if I really want to test another beta :-/ However, the answer to my question: it's a bug.

**Edit** Jumped over my own shadow and tested with the last beta (4). Issue has been fixed.